# Navigate to page with parameter without OnNavigateTo method in codebehind

Tags: c#, design-patterns, mvvm, windows-store-apps, mvvm-light

I'm developing an Windows 8 Store App.
I want pass a parameter when I navigate to another page in my app.

I'm using the MVVMLight toolkit and I use the `.Navigate(string Type, object param)` method from the `NavigationService` which implements `INavigationService`.

I can navigate to the page and use the parameter, but just when I use the `OnNavigateTo(NavigationArgs e)` method.

In fact I just want the parameter in the ViewModel of the second page without using any code in the codebehind of the second page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging.Messenger to communicate within your application.
Please refer http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/09/27/mvvm-light-toolkit-messenger-v2-beta.aspx
for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my implementation of MVVM Navigation via an Interface and it's implementation

It's as simple as doing   `_navigationService.Navigate<Map>(false);`

(I'm navigating to the ViewModel Map, and my NavigationService just knows that X ViewModel is mapped to X.xaml page!)

More at https://github.com/cmorgado/MultiPlatform